# sql wildcard not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a query that displays the employee’s Full Name and Job Title in the following format:

--          DAVIES, CURTIS is ST_CLERK

Only employees whose last name ends with S and first name starts with C or K.
It runs but something is happening with the 3rd line and nothing is printing even though there are a few people who meet the criteria

```
SELECT LAST_NAME ||', '|| FIRST_NAME || ' is ' || JOB_ID AS "PERSON AND JOB"
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE (LAST_NAME LIKE '%S') AND (FIRST_NAME LIKE 'C%' OR FIRST_NAME LIKE 'K%');
```

EDIT:
Found the answer, S is supposed to be the last letter and I have it capitalized.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the original data in your table, formatted properly.

Comment: Are you certain that there aren't any whitespace/unprintable characters after the `S` or before the `C`/`K`?

Comment: Debugging 101: Break it down into smaller pieces. Do you get results just checking the `LAST_NAME` in the where clause? How about when just checking `FIRST_NAME`?

Comment: Found the answer, S is supposed to be the last letter and I have it capitalized.

Comment: Just a suggestion but you could upper last_name and first_name if you wish to avoid this kind of issues in the future.  That way, you'll only with upper or lower case depending on your choice

Comment: @ortz3 Glad you found the problem, but your example of "DAVIES, CURTIS" shows the name in all caps. This highlights the importance of providing accurate sample data with your question.

Comment: Wrap an UPPER around the column names and then use uppercase literals ... just to be sure.

Comment: Yes, thank you guys. Converting to uppercase is a very good technique to never have to worry about whether something is lower or upper case because it will all be upper case

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure, I would recommend forcing the last name and first name into uppercase in the Where clause:

```
  (UPPER(LAST_NAME) LIKE '%S' 
AND (UPPER(FIRST_NAME) LIKE 'C%' OR UPPER(FIRST_NAME) LIKE 'K%')
```

This worked for me in my test.

Comment: That would prevent any indexes (except FBI) on the colums being considered. Not that it would really matter with `like` here, but it's still something to be wary of generally.